# Grunt fails with No Such File or Directory (looking in gems)

Tags: linux, rubygems, gruntjs

Ok,

Whenever I try running grunt serve or any grunt command for that matter it responds with:

> grunt
>
> bash: /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/grunt: No such file or directory

Why is it looking in gems? And how do I get this fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

The solution was:

1. gem uninstall grunt
2. gem uninstall grunt (make sure it is gone)
3. npm update -g npm (make sure npm is up to date)
4. gem update --system (make sure all the gems have been updated - including updating the removal of the grunt gem file)

And that should have it all working.